# Can I electrify a pin by applying current in its base?

Tags: electricity

I imagine electric circuits as loops. So I wonder, if it is possible to electrify a pin without connecting its two edges, instead only applying current at its base. But I want the current to run across its tip. Is that possible? And if yes, how will the current flow exactly, i.e. what will the path of the electrons be?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, using an AC current, but no electrons will flow. Alternatively you can get field emission of electrons from the tip by applying a large negative voltage.

Comment: _I want the current to run across its tip._  Why?  What do you hope to achieve?  Or, in other words, what do you mean by "electrify a pin?"

Comment: Closing because cross-posting is not appreciated: http://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/5296/624

Comment: why is not appreciated? what is wrong with it?

Comment: Cross posting is generally discouraged, but its not a legitimate reason to vote to close.

Comment: For anyone considering voting to close as Unclear, seeing the cross-posted question might be helpful, as it was edited by the OP.

Comment: @CuriousOne what's with all the answers in the comments? Nothing wrong with typing characters into the answer box.

Answer (score 1):

If you charge a pin, most of the charge will accumulate in the tip, but you can't have current unless the charge is going somewhere. That's like asking for a waterfall without letting the water move.

You could take two pins, separated by an insulator, with joined tips, then apply voltage across the two bases. Then you'd have current flowing through the tip.

Beyond that, you'll need to explain what you're hoping to accomplish with this pin before people are likely to give you a better answer.